# What makes a web site 'finished' for delivery to a client?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

Sorry if this question has already been answered, and sorry if it's too subjective to make sense, or for StackOverflow.

I'm delivering a site to a client and I want to send them high-quality HTML/CSS/JS, fully validated, accessible etc.

So I'm compiling a list of things to check, and useful tools for doing so, before I hand the code over. Here's a partial list, but what am I missing?

- **Link checking** for any broken links I might have missed - [W3C link checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink)
- **HTML validation** for accessibility and broken-ness - [W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/)
- **CSS validation** - [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)
- **Check for slow-loading page elements** - Firebug and [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) plugin

What's missing - if you were a client, what else would you want to be sure has been checked?

I'm wondering about the etiquette of things like comments, indentation, and minification; is it good practice to sort out all these? And what else have I missed?

Thanks :)

Comment: A list of things to know when building a public website (you'll probably find a lot more things to test for after reading it, especially security related): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

Comment: excellent list there, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some famous checklist:

http://launchlist.net/

[EDIT] and another: http://www.boxuk.com/blog/the-ultimate-website-launch-checklist

Comment: Just had a look at http://launchlist.net/, it looks amazing! Definitely not exhaustive, but still pretty damn good!

+1

Answer (score 3):

I can't help but feel **you're doing things the wrong way around**...

I prefer where all the **requirements are agreed up-front** with the client, so that you know when all those items are checked off, you are done.

Comment: It seems a bit unprofessional asking the client what he expects to be done aside from his requirements.  If I were the client and I were asked what needed to be checked before handing the site over to me, considering a lot of clients won't have the technical expertise to know what should be checked, I'd probably go elsewhere :-)

Comment: @Andy - I'm not talking about asking the client about the technical details and what should or shouldn't be included, I'm suggesting that developer and client sit down at the start and agree on a checklist of individual deliverables, which once done, will indicate that the project has come to an end.

Comment: Thanks @Galwegian - I'm really asking about the kind of stuff (accessibility, validation, security) that a technical client would take for granted, and a non-technical client wouldn't even know existed :) I guess I'm asking what I need to check to do a good job for the client, whether they know it or not!

Comment: Maybe that is a bit subjective... the lists supplied so far are a good start though.

Answer (score 1):

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)? Checks JavaScript correctness. (Warning: JSLint will hurt your feelings.)

Answer (score 0):

Does it degrade gracefully? (Does the site function correctly with JavaScript disabled?)

Comment: Not sure that's a delivery requirement, more a spec issue: if it's specced to degrade gracefully it should do it, if not it shouldn't.

Comment: I don't agree.. I feel that in the absence of JavaScript in a browser it must degrade gracefully and continue functioning correctly.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918450/when-its-ok-to-use-javascript-and-when-not/2918474#2918474

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to the things you *could* check, have a look at this [Smashing Magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/29/45-incredibly-useful-web-design-checklists-and-questionnaires/) which has lots of lists to check before deployment.

This is probably information overload, but what I did is make a list that is specific to me, now and again I add to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but feel that browser testing is missing from your list. Nothing beats looking at the site in every browser you can get your hands on.